# Threading, DirectX and XAML on WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, directx

I've worked with DirectX native project and got better performance using a separate thread to handle the HARD work asyncronous while keeping the ui responsive, but when I try to do the same with XAML/DirectX app I get wrost performace! My guess is that the XAML thread blocks any secondary thread while active(drawing to screen). Anyone know how to use native threads on a XAML app?

Comment: Can you give a specific example (with code) of a perf problem you're seeing?

Comment: There's not a specific code I can add, the C# XAML call the DX component(DrawingSurfaceBackground) to update the screen, then I start the thread "th = new std::thread(myheavyfunc())" and use mutexes to comunicate with it, and at each new call to update I check if myheavyfunc() finished a frame. The problem is that myheavyfunc() runs slower than without using the thread(blocking the UI thread until finish a frame) but using native DX app I get great speed increase by letting myheavyfunc() run in the background continually.